# getting epoll descriptor from boost asio io_service object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Can we get the epoll descriptor underlying the boost asio io_service object ?? we have multiple boost asio io_service objects in our application, one from a library and the other native to the application, the io_service object from the library is a server object serving multiple connections, we are investigating how best we can coordinate multiple io_service objects efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you don't need to break the documented interface to combine both.

In fact the documented interface is enough to combine several io_service objects efficiently.

Basically the only point of efficiency you could be looking for is to avoid running separate event loops for them (as that might require more threads than you're prepared to).

As [the docs say](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html):

> The library interface is decoupled from interfaces for thread creation and management, and permits implementations on platforms where threads are not available.

And the [platform specific implementation notes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html#boost_asio.overview.implementation.linux_kernel_2_6) promise (in slightly different but essentially similar wording):

> Demultiplexing using epoll is performed in one of the threads that calls io_context::run(), io_context::run_one(), io_context::poll() or io_context::poll_one().

This is your clue. You can knit together many `io_service`s into a single event loop using `poll_one()` (or even `run_one()`). In fact, this mechanism can be used to integrate with whatever thrid-party event subsystem you want (libev, Qt idle work etc.). You could call `poll_one()` in response to a hardware interrupt on systems that don't support threads in the first place.

As a side-note, the inverse is to let other libraries do native socket operations with ASIO doing the polling: [Reactor Style Operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html).

Both these approaches can be combined.

### Summary

Boost Asio is designed to be extensible and to be unintrusive to your design choices. You're most likely able to "fix" your third-party library integration worries using the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of boost there are methods run_for and run_until, we can wait on the first io service object for a specified time and can call poll on the second io service object when the first one returns or times out.